# set_cursor_position(...); doesn't scroll the console

Tags: c

I made a function that moves the cursor down on the Y axis when down arrow is pressed in the console using set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
But it just won't go below the currently not-displayed part of the console. I have to manually scroll down for that to happen and it messes up the whole function in strange ways.
The function:

```
int scanArrow(int limit, int X, int Y, char fgr, char bgr)
{
    int place = 0, axisX = X, axisY = Y;
    unsigned char ch;

    if (limit > 0)
    {
        printColor(axisX, axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
        do
        {
            ch = getch();
            if (ch == 0 || ch == 0xE0)
            {
                ch = getch();
                switch (ch)
                {
                case KEY_UP:
                    if (place > 0)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY--;
                        printColor(axisX, --axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place--;
                    }
                    break;
                case KEY_DOWN:
                    if (place + 1 < limit)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY++;
                        printColor(axisX, ++axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place++;
                    }
                    break;
                case KEY_LEFT:
                    if (place > 9)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY = axisY - 20;
                        printColor(axisX, axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place = place - 10;
                    }
                    else if (place > 0)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY = Y;
                        printColor(axisX, axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case KEY_RIGHT:
                    if (place + 10 < limit)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY = axisY + 20;
                        printColor(axisX, axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place = place + 10;
                    }
                    else if (place + 1 < limit)
                    {
                        printf(" \b");
                        axisY = Y + ((limit-1) * 2);
                        printColor(axisX, axisY, "*", fgr, bgr);
                        set_cursor_position(axisX, axisY);
                        place = limit - 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while ((ch != KEY_ENTER) && (ch != KEY_ESC));
        return place+1;
    }
    else
    {
        return place;
    }
}
```

Technically, it prints a "*" and moves it vertically with the help of up and down arrows (left and right are up and down (x10))
I am using it for giving the user to choose from a menu using the arrows instead of typing something, but it's not working if the menu's height is bigger than the console itself.

The set_cursor_position:

```
void set_cursor_position(int x, int y)
{
        COORD c;
        HANDLE hCons;
        hCons = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        c.X = x;
        c.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCons, c);
        return;
}
```

Comment: And what do the function do? How does it work? What console are you using (Windows command window? Windows PowerShell? OSX/Linux terminal?)

Comment: Windows command console
I am debugging using Visual Studio 2013
I will edit the code in a sec

Comment: I'm more interested in the `set_cursor_position` function, as that's what seems to be causing you trouble. Also note that the console window is not like a graphical window where you can draw outside the window (even if it doesn't show). The console window is only the console window, that's all you have. The only way to go to positions outside the window is if the user enlarges the windows, in which case you still have only the window to work upon, it just is a little larger.

Comment: I will add the set_cursor_position code in a sec too.
Even tho it is not like a graphical window, how can I make this work?
Some function for scrolling the console or something?
Because lets say we have a lot of printf's that print \n . Eventually this makes a scroll-bar and the console automatically scrolls once for each \n you have that is outside it's bounds. Well it doesn't happen here. Should I find a way by printing \n ? I am not sure how possible that is, given that we already have text printed there it might get affected, erased or something.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You can't go down further than the current console buffer, the last line in the buffer is the last line available to you.

Comment: I decided to make it by adding different pages, I saw that "ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer" function but my teacher told me it's smarter to go for turning a list into a few pages. Thanks for the help.